# Uploadify to database

Tags: asp.net, jquery, uploadify

i have a asp.net FileUpload control and below is the code (which works fine)

```
 if (fUpload.HasFile)   
 {        
    string contentType = fUpload.PostedFile.ContentType;        
    string fileName = fUpload.PostedFile.FileName;       
    byte[] byteArray = fUpload.FileBytes;  
    ........         
 }
```

**but i'm thinking of using the JQuery plugin Uploadify**
    how would you convert the above code in Uploadify?, i got stuck here

```
byte[] byteArray = fUpload.FileBytes;   // i dont find "FileBytes"
```

Comment: http://casonclagg.com/articles/6/video-tutorial-uploadify-asp-net-c-sharp.aspx mybe this helps, i dont know anything about asp.net but used uploadify with php.

Comment: thanks, i am looking for uploading the files to database but the link shows how to upload to filesystem

Comment: Client-script can't access the file bytes.  You'll have to POST it to the server, and then save it to the database there.  You can't directly upload to the database using client-script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you are using the uploadify control you should have something in your markup like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       // <![CDATA[
       var id = "55";
       var theString = "asdf";
       $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#fileInput').uploadify({
       'uploader': 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
       'script': 'Upload.ashx',
       'scriptData': { 'id': id, 'foo': theString},
       'cancelImg': 'uploadify/cancel.png',
       'auto': true,
       'multi': true,
       'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
       'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.bmp;*.jpeg',
       'queueSizeLimit': 90,
       'sizeLimit': 4000000,
       'buttonText': 'Choose Images',
       'folder': '/uploads',
       'onAllComplete': function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {

       }
     });
   });
   // ]]></script>

   <input id="fileInput" name="fileInput" type="file" />
```

Then you want to have a Generic Handler, which is an ashx file.  What happens is this handler gets called when the uploadify control wants to upload one of the files in the Queue that it has.  Open VS -> Right click your project -> Add New -> Choose Generic Handler -> Name it something like Upload.ashx.

Take that file and put something similar to this in there:

```
public class Upload : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpPostedFile file= context.Request.Files["Filedata"];

            int id = (Int32.Parse(context.Request["id"]));
            string foo = context.Request["foo"];
            file.SaveAs("C:\\" + id.ToString() + foo + file.FileName);

            context.Response.Write("1");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            context.Response.Write("0");
        }
    }
}
```

It comes by default with an IsReusable()...DONT DELETE IT.  Its required, just leave it in there or you will get a strange error.

Also, you can watch it step by step here: http://casonclagg.com/articles/6/video-tutorial-uploadify-asp-net-c-sharp.aspx

**EDIT**

I think you want to do this, where file is a HttpPostedFile object:

```
BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
byte[] binaryData = b.ReadBytes(file.InputStream.Length);
```

Comment: i just started implementing this and i endup having issues, have you tried working with master page? with update-panel ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by working with Masterpage and UpdatePanel.  Yes I have worked with both, but I'm not sure how that fits in with your question.  What are your issues you are having?

Comment: where do i find the sample that uses masterpage/content page using updatepanel have you done similar to like this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working behind a CMS or are having still having issues make sure you allow the location path in your web.config file as below.

```
<location path="Upload.ashx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```